# Miniature Pixel art program using JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have just recently gotten into Java and am a still a noob. I have created a 9x9 panel of JPanels using a for loop to add the buttons. How would I create an action listener that would allow me to choose different colors that will appear as the background color of the JButton when clicked? I'm trying to make a miniature pixel art program.

Comment: if you show me your code, I can help. Otherwise, it is almost impossible to help you.

Comment: I'm not within wifi right now but I will send it when I can

Comment: OK. you need to have something like a counter, which increases every time you hit the button. then add a bunch of `if` and `else if` statements, based on if the counter is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.

Comment: `"I'm trying to make a miniature pixel art program."` -- If I'm understanding you correctly, JButtons don't seem appropriate for this. Rather wouldn't you want to add a MouseListener to a JPanel and change the color drawn in its paintComponent mthod of the clicked spots? Please show your code **and** tell more of the pertinent details of your problem. And avoid asking such questions when you're not in a position to do the above as you risk getting the question closed and/or down-voted.

Comment: Yes normally that would be the ideal thing but I am bound by specific constraints that I have to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will look something like this. In this example, `[row]` and `[col]` refer to the row and column values of your grid. Be sure to create counter (`private static int counter = 0;`). or else you will get a bunch of errors. Here is the Code:

```
JBut[row][col].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        typeOfButton button = (typeOfButton) e.getSource();
        int row = button.getRow();
        int col = button.getCol();

        counter++;
        if (counter == 1) {
            JBut[row][col].setBackground(Color.RED);
        } 
        else if (counter == 2) {
            JBut[row][col].setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        } 
        else if (counter == 3) {
            JBut[row][col].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        } 
        else if (counter == 4) {
            JBut[row][col].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } 
        else if (counter == 5){
            JBut[row][col].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        } 
        else if (counter == 6){
            JBut[row][col].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        } 
        else {
            JBut[row][col].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            counter = 0; //makes color cycle repeat, starting with red
        } //end else
    } //end actionPerformed
}); //end ActionListener
```

Obviously, the simple way to do this would be to put the giant `if` statement in a new method called `determineColor()` or something like that.